# Swift multiple parameter names are working strangely

Tags: swift

I'm testing several thing about Swift so far and found something strange.

Belows are 2 methods I'm testing.

```
func testFunction(param1:String, param2:String, param3:Int)   {

}

func testFunction2(param1 param1:String, param2 param2:String, param3 param3:Int)   {

}
```

As long as I understand, the function call of the above methods should be as follows.

```
testFunction("a", "b", 3)
testFunction2(param1:"a", param2:"b", param3:3)
```

The `testFunction2` is working fine, but the `testFunction` is not invoked like this. The compiler said

```
testFunction("a", param2:"b", param3:3)
```

is the correct syntax. Why?

When parameter and external name is the same, I can use `#`. So I tried

```
func testFunction2(#param1:String, #param2:String, #param3:Int)   {

}
```

but compiler says

```
func testFunction2(#param1:String, param2:String, param3:Int)   {

}
```

is correct and the second function worked as I expected.

Am I missing something?

**ADDED**

[image]

It's the Apple's swift guide doc (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_245)

Comment: Not missing anything--methods are by default called with the first parameter name omitted, so you only need to add the `#` sign to the first parameter name. In your second function you're providing *external* parameter names for the parameters (even though they're the same), so the compiler doesn't mind.

Comment: @AstroCB// No, I'm using official release of Xcode6

Comment: @NateCook// Thanks. The document from the Apple is wrong. right?

Comment: Not wrong - that documentation is for *functions*, which are defined at the top level. The behavior you're seeing is the behavior for *methods*, which are part of a type (class, struct, or enum). Look at the "Local and External Parameter Names for Methods" section of the [Methods chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_346).

Comment: @NateCook// That's what I've missed. Thanks a lot!